# powerDNS - how can I fix slave received malformed Qdomain?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, powerdns

This is my syslog file,

`/var/log/syslog`

```
Mar  8 18:10:56 ns2 pdns[4205]: Received a malformed qdomain from 74.125.183.72, '192.243.111.209;.anim.ga': sending servfail
Mar  8 18:11:01 ns2 pdns[4205]: Received a malformed qdomain from 74.125.183.199, '192.243.111.209;.anim.ga': sending servfail
Mar  8 18:11:01 ns2 pdns[4205]: Received a malformed qdomain from 74.125.72.143, '192.243.111.209;.anim.ga': sending servfail
Mar  8 18:11:01 ns2 pdns[4205]: Received a malformed qdomain from 74.125.72.7, '192.243.111.209;.anim.ga': sending servfail
Mar  8 18:11:04 ns2 pdns[4205]: Received a malformed qdomain from 74.125.72.129, '192.243.111.209;.anim.ga': sending servfail
Mar  8 18:11:04 ns2 pdns[4205]: Received a malformed qdomain from 74.125.183.65, '192.243.111.209;.anim.ga': sending servfail
Mar  8 18:11:04 ns2 pdns[4205]: Received a malformed qdomain from 74.125.72.137, '192.243.111.209;.anim.ga': sending servfail
Mar  8 18:11:07 ns2 pdns[4205]: Received a malformed qdomain from 74.125.183.76, '192.243.111.209;.anim.ga': sending servfail
Mar  8 18:11:07 ns2 pdns[4205]: Received a malformed qdomain from 74.125.72.149, '192.243.111.209;.anim.ga': sending servfail
Mar  8 18:11:07 ns2 pdns[4205]: Received a malformed qdomain from 74.125.183.67, '192.243.111.209;.anim.ga': sending servfail
```

My MYSQL record table:

```
+----+-----------+---------+------+-----------------+------+------+-------------+-----------+------+
| id | domain_id | name    | type | content         | ttl  | prio | change_date | ordername | auth |
+----+-----------+---------+------+-----------------+------+------+-------------+-----------+------+
|  1 |         1 | anim.ga | SOA  | NULL            | NULL | NULL |  1457472468 | NULL      | NULL |
|  2 |         1 | anim.ga | NS   | ns1.anim.ga     | NULL | NULL |  1457472468 | NULL      | NULL |
|  3 |         1 | anim.ga | NS   | ns2.anim.ga     | NULL | NULL |  1457472468 | NULL      | NULL |
|  4 |         1 | anim.ga | A    | 192.243.111.209 | NULL | NULL |  1457472468 | NULL      | NULL |
+----+-----------+---------+------+-----------------+------+------+-------------+-----------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My domains table:

```
+----+---------+--------+------------+--------+-----------------+---------+
| id | name    | master | last_check | type   | notified_serial | account |
+----+---------+--------+------------+--------+-----------------+---------+
|  1 | anim.ga | NULL   |       NULL | MASTER |            NULL | NULL    |
+----+---------+--------+------------+--------+-----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Finally config file:

```
#################################
# Autogenerated configuration file template
#################################
# allow-axfr-ips    If enabled, restrict zonetransfers to originate from these
#                   IP addresses
#
# allow-axfr-ips=
default-soa-mail=admin.anim.ga
default-soa-name=ns1.anim.ga
launch=gmysql
soa-minimum-ttl=3600
soa-refresh-default=10800
soa-retry-default=3600
slave=yes
#master=yes;
```

Anything else you may need I will provide.

Answer (score 0):

those IPs are Google's, I bet they are part of the 8.8.8.8 cluster. The queries you are seeing - people are actually sending them to 8.8.8.8, presumably because of a misconfiguration somewhere. You cannot prevent this from within your PowerDNS. You can hide the message by disabling `log-dns-details` (i.e. `log-dns-details=off`).